# Why are code blocks and code literals displaying with large face in markdown

Tags: faces, fonts, font-lock, markdown, markdown-mode

In markdown mode, all of the fenced code blocks and inline code literal strings are displaying with this very large font. The size is large, and also I'm pretty sure it isn't the same font as the default surrounding text (which is *Classic Console*).

[image]

---

This is Emacs 25.3 on a Mac, using the standalone app
(the one from https://emacsformacosx.com/).

My [.emacs file is here](https://gist.github.com/adammichaelwood/c7bf9d8b4a5adc5ecbb39d3bfc3a2dfd).

Comment: Are you asking why the default font sizes are thus? If so, ask the library author. Or are you asking why your customizations give font sizes like this? If so, bisect your init file to find out. Or are you asking something else? The question is unclear. Please don't just give a link to your init file and ask people here to tell you why you get what you get from your customizations.

Comment: If you like the built-in customization features to change the appearance of something, then place your cursor at the location of whatever you want to change and type `M-x customize-face`.  If there is more than one thing happening at the particular location at issue, type `C-u C-x =` and read about what's there to determine what things you may wish to customize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be fixed by calling `M-x customize-group RET markdown-faces` while in Markdown mode. It opens a menu of various font face settings. Under `Markdown Code Face`, uncheck/delete everything and then save. This will make the code face the same as the default face.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `Adam Michael Wood` and `lawlist`:

`C-u C-x =` - good way to get information about font symbol

[image: Information about symbol's font]

In appered buffer you should follow that paragraph: `There are text properties here:` and visit highlighted link. This way can help you look through font inheritance.

You can get clear that `Mardown Code Face` inherits Emacs system `fixed-pitch` root-font.

[image: Fixed pitch font options]

`(customize this face)` - Opens Emacs font editor

Or you can change this settings in your `.emacs` file

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono" :foundry "DAMA" :slant normal :weight normal :height 107 :width normal))))
  )
```

Append next line after `default font`:

```
 '(fixed-pitch ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono"))))
```